# Binding certain parameter fields in complex object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following web api 2 request.

I'm having issues binding the AccountTypeIdentifier and AccountTypeCode properties when I have a query string values of /api/Accounts?ID=1&AccountTypeIdentifier=1,2,3...

Controller

```
    ...
    public IHttpActionResult GetAccounts([fromuri]GetAccountsRequest request)
    ...
```

Object

```
    [DataContract]
    public class GetAccountsRequest {

    [DataMember]
    public int ID {get; set;}

    [DataMemeber]
    public IEnumerable<int?> AccountTypeIdentifier {get; set;}

    [DataMemeber]
    public IEnumerable<string> AccountTypeCode {get;set;}
    ....
    }
```

I was thinking of implementing a custom modelbinder for this case but I'm wondering if its possible just to handle the custom modelbinder for the IEnumerable types and not my other fields in the GetAccountsRequest object because the default model binder works.

If I created a ModelBinder would I have to bind every field in the GetAccountsRequest myself or is there a way to call the base implementation of the ModelBinder?